# ASP.NET "SQL0519: Prepared statement S000001 in use." DB2

Tags: asp.net, db2, ibm-midrange

> SQL0519: Prepared statement S000001 in use. Cause . . . . . :   The
>   application program has attempted to prepare statement S000001. This
>   statement is the SELECT statement for cursor C000001 that is currently
>   open. Recovery  . . . :   Change the statement name in the PREPARE
>   statement or correct the logic of the application program so that it
>   closes cursor C000001 before attempting the PREPARE statement again.

I have an ASP.NET web application that runs SQL queries on an iSeries Database. When I run locally through the virtual Visual Studio 2000 Web Server, everything works fine.

I uploaded onto an IIS server and now I get the above error everytime an SQL statement is run.  I am using an XML SQLDataSource to populate a GridView.

Is there something else I can try adding to the code?  An IIS congfiguration issue perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

The error message is indicating that the cursor has not been closed before trying to PREPARE again.  Try this sequence:

```
loop
  PREPARE cursor
  OPEN cursor
  loop
    FETCH from cursor
  end loop 
  CLOSE cursor
end loop
```

Comment: The GridView SqlDataSource manages all that by itself.  I never explicitly open/close the cursor.